# Is there a relation between $End(M)$ and $M$ under tensor products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be an $R$-module (If necessary, you can assume more conditions)

Let $\phi$ be an $R$-endomorphism on $M$ and $\overline{\phi}:M^{\otimes n}\rightarrow M^{\otimes n}$ be the tensor product of $\phi$. (I used the notation $\overline{\phi}$ to distinguish the one that will come below)

Now let consider the tensor power of $End(M)$. That is, $End(M)^{\otimes n}$. And consider a tensor of it, namely, $\phi^{\otimes n}$.

Is there a relation between $\overline{\phi}$ and $\phi^{\otimes n}$?

I think the reason why I'm asking this is I don't actually have a picture of the concept tensor..

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Could you explain in some details please?

Comment: What is $V$? You've been talking about $R$-modules $M$ for a while, then suddenly you ask about $V$, which usually indicates you are talking about vector sapces.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Edited. Since I had this question when I was seeing a post here aboit vector space, i made that mistake applogy

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: false.

Comment: There is a canonical $R$-module homomorphism $\left(\operatorname{End} M\right)^{\otimes n} \to \operatorname{End} \left(M^{\otimes n}\right)$ which sends $\phi^{\otimes n}$ to $\overline{\phi}$. And that's all that can be said in general. This map might fail to be injective, and might fail to be surjective. There are criteria for its bijectivity similar to those in Bernard's answer, but they all take some conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case $n=2$. The only general answer I know is this: by the universal property of  tensor products, given $R$-modules $M_1,M_2,N_1, N_2$ there is a canonical homomorphism:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom_R(M_1,N_1)\otimes_R\Hom_R(M_2,N_2)\to\Hom_R(M_1\otimes_RM_2, N_1\otimes_R N_2)$$
and this homomorphism is an isomorphism if one of the pairs $(M_1,M_2)$, $(M_1,N_1)$, $(M_2,N_2)$ consists in finitely generated projective $R$-modules (Bourbaki, *Algebra, Ch. II, Linear Algebra*, §4 no4, prop.4).
 So in your the answer is they're isomorphic for finite projective $R$-modules.

*Note:*  This covers the case of finite dimensional vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{enclose}$
I just reformulate the rusults form vector spaces that i know.

For any modules $M_1,N_1,M_2,N_2$ there is an $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{injective}}$ (EDIT. Apparently injectivity doesn't hold for modules over rings. Modules require additional conditions.) mapping $$j:Hom(M_1,N_1)\otimes Hom(M_2,N_2)\rightarrow Hom(M_1\otimes M_2,N_1\otimes N_2),$$ 
such that $$j(\phi\otimes\psi)(m_1\otimes m_2)=\phi(m_1)\otimes \psi (m_2).$$
So we can identify elements in $Hom(M_1,N_1)\otimes Hom(M_2,N_2)$ with elements in $Hom(M_1\otimes M_2,N_1\otimes N_2)$ (if this additional conditions hold). Hence given simple $\phi\in End(M)^{\otimes n}$ we can think of this as an element of $End(M^{\otimes n}).$ So
$$\phi^{\otimes n}(m_1\otimes\dots\otimes m_n)=\phi(m_1)\otimes\dots\otimes \phi(m_n)=\bar\phi(m_1\otimes\dots\otimes m_n).$$

---

If you want to read more, here is the reference:
Greub, *Multilinear Algebra*, Springer 1967.