# The relationship of $\hom(M\otimes_RN,M'\otimes_RN')$ and $\hom_R(M,M')\otimes\hom_R(N,N')$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products, additive-categories

Let $R$ be a ring with identity, $M$ and $M'$ two right $R$-module, $N$ and $N'$ two left $R$-module. There is a natural way to define a homomorphism

$$f:\hom_R(M,M')  \otimes \hom_R(N,N')\to
    \hom(M\otimes_R N, M'\otimes_RN').$$

My question is that, is $f$ always monic, epic, or isomorphic? And if any answer is no, then is there any characterization of the case when $f$ is so?

Comment: Recently there was a discussion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306415/is-there-a-relation-between-endm-and-m-under-tensor-products

Comment: What is the structure of $M \otimes_R N$? Is it only a group (i think it is neither a left-module nor right module)? And what is a homomophism from a right-module to a left module (the formula $f(x\lambda)=\lambda f(x)$ seems to be inconsistant)?

Comment: @user10676 When I write $\hom$ (or $⊗$) istead of $\hom_R$ (or $⊗_R$), I mean $\hom_{\mathbb Z}$ (or $⊗_{\mathbb Z}$). But as user244913's answer pointed out, that makes this question bizarre...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm sorry that's due to a stupid mistake. It has been fixed now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are considering not necessarily commutative ring and thus is forced to taking hom-set and tensor product of abelian group, it's not reasonable to expect that $\hom_R(M,M')\otimes\hom_R(N,N')$ and $\hom(M\otimes_RN,M'\otimes_RN')$ are comparable. For example, taking $M:=R_R,N:=_RR$, then the two become $R\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\hom_R(M',N')$ and $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(R,M'\otimes_RN')$, which can be very different.

I suggest that you could consider a similar and more natural question: for commutative ring $R$, when $f:\hom_R(M,M')\otimes_R\hom_R(N,N')\to\hom_R(M\otimes_RN,M'\otimes_RN')$ is epic, monic, or isomorphic, of which a link of the partial solution has been given in the comment.